# How to add static in my django

Tags: django

my folder structure is as below:

```
mysite_new/
          manage.py
          mysite/
                 __init__.py
                 urls.py
                 setting.py
                 wsgi.py
                 templates/
                          default.html
                 static/
                        admin/
                              img/
                                  logo.png

          ticket/
                __init__.py
                models.py
                view.py
                urls.py
                ......
```

In setting.py, i set

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '' 
STATICFILES_DIRS = (

)
```

and in ticket/urls.py i set

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT )
```

## default.html

```
<html>
<head>
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/img/logo.jpg" />

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Then i try to access the page which contains the default.html, the logo.jpg is not shown.
It shows [image]

So may be the static folder is not link to my project correctly, my question is who can tell me how to implement this?
 What should i set in `setting.py` ( STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL, STATICFILES_DIRS) ,`urls.py` and how to modify the `default.html`. Please give the detail steps in very short. Thanks

Comment: When you create a django project, it's automatically setted. Did you remove it?

Answer (score 2):

I think for dev mode you need to set

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

and in urls.py

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

To collectstatic you need to set STATIC_ROOT like:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '..', 'static')
```